# Is is to possible to create an active Clickwrap with API?

Tags: docusignapi

I'm trying to create an active Clickwrap using Clickwrap API, but the Clickwrap always end as inactive.
It is possible to create an active CLickwrap using API ?
My request body:

```
# Step 3: Construct your clickwrap JSON body
$body = @"
{

  "status": "active",
  "name": "Contrat",
  "requireReacceptance": false,

  "displaySettings": {
    "consentButtonText": "Signer",
    "declineButtonText": "Abandonner",
    "displayName": "Contrat",
    "downloadable": true,
    "format": "inline",
    "hasAccept": true,
    "mustRead": true,
    "mustView": true,
    "requireAccept": true,
    "size": "medium",
    "documentDisplay": "document"
  },
  "documents": [
    {
      "documentBase64": "JVBERi0(...)jcyYWY3M2Q5NmNhMD4KPGM0MGU2ZTE3NmU3YzA0MWZiMjhiNzJhZjczZDk2Y2EwPiBdID4+CnN0YXJ0eHJlZgoyNjc0MwolJUVPRgo=",
      "documentName": "Contrat",
      "fileExtension": "pdf",
      "order": 0
    }
  ]

}
"@
```

Comment: What is the response object? Please EDIT your question to add the information.

Answer (score 2):

You need to make another API call to activate the clickwrap. You do it like this:

```
   # Make a PUT call to the clickwraps endpoint to activate created
    # clickwrap
    uri = f"{CLICKWRAP_BASE_URI}/{ds_client.account_id}/clickwraps/{clickwrap_id}/versions/1"
    response_active = ds_client.api_client.call_api(
        uri, 'PUT', body={'status': 'active'}, response_type='object'
    )
    return response_active[0]
```